# Unity - Gizmos not being drawn properly from Inherited class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I am having an Issue regarding Gizmos being drawn this issue is specific to 2 classes

**Interactable()** and **Door() : Interactable()**

inside **Interactable()** I have:

```
void OnDrawGizmos () {
    Gizmos.color = Color.grey;
    if (transform.parent != null) {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere ( transform.parent.position, interactionDist );
    } else {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere ( transform.position, interactionDist );
    }
}
```

*is being used for interaction area ( regarding door they are child of Frame of the door )*

and inside **Door() : Interactible()**

```
void OnDrawGizmos () {
    Gizmos.matrix = transform.parent.localToWorldMatrix;
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube ( openDistance, Vector3.one);
}
```

Issue is that Gizmo created inside **Door()** is being properly shown while Wire Sphere from **Interactable()** is completely missing.

[image: Door Gizmo]

But for other scripts which inherit from **Interactable()** shows Gizmos properly

[image: Objects with different script]

Only difference i can think off is that others scripts which inherit from this behavior don't have **OnDrawGizmos()** class.

Could somebody point me out in direction in which i would be able to draw both of them at the same time ?

Thank you.

Edit:
After little change and answer from **rustyBucketBay** worked for me.
Sorry for huge amount of Edits.

Updated code:

```
new void OnDrawGizmos () {
    base.OnDrawGizmos ();
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube (transform.parent.position + openDistance, Vector3.one );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to comment out the `Gizmos.matrix = transform.parent.localToWorldMatrix;` to see the yellow cube.

To see both you need to call the `OnDrawGizmos()` of the base class in the `OnDrawGizmos()` of the child class like this:

```
void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        base.OnDrawGizmos();
        //Gizmos.matrix = transform.parent.localToWorldMatrix;
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(transform.position, Vector3.one);
    }
```